# Enable dragging for custom QgsAttributeTableView class PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I have this custom class for adding an attribute table to my plugin:

```
class CustomAttributeTableWidget(QWidget):
def __init__(self, frame, layer, canvas):
    super().__init__(frame)
    # first clear everying from the frame

    self.layout = QVBoxLayout(frame)
    self.tableView = QgsAttributeTableView()
    self.tableView.setDragEnabled(True)

    self.layout.addWidget(self.tableView)

    self.initializeAttributeTable(layer, canvas)
    frame.setLayout(self.layout)

def initializeAttributeTable(self, layer, canvas):
    self.layerCache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, layer.featureCount())
    self.tableModel = QgsAttributeTableModel(self.layerCache)
    self.tableModel.loadLayer()
    
    self.tableFilterModel = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(canvas, self.tableModel)
    self.tableFilterModel.setFilterMode(QgsAttributeTableFilterModel.ShowAll)
    
    self.tableView.setModel(self.tableFilterModel)
    self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

But setDragEnabled(True) does nothing it seems. I want to be able to drag from this table in my plugin. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The drag-drop behavior on a tableView GUI is actually realized by defining a tableModel that connects to the tableView.

The drag-drop behavior acts on the item of the tableModel. When using `QStandardItemModel` as the tableView's backend model, each item in a `QStandardItemModel` is a `QStandardItem`, which supports the drag-drop behavior. However, for a `QgsAttributeTableModel`, which is inherited from `QAbstractTableModel`, each item in it is a `QgsFeature` object, which has no drag-drop behavior defined on it.

If you really want the drag-drop behavior, you have to redefine a new table model class and the item class related to it.

If you just want to copy content from the attribute table to your plugin, you can add some code to your `initializeAttributeTable` function to enable editing:

```
def initializeAttributeTable(self, layer, canvas):
    layer.setReadOnly(False) #new code
    layer.startEditing() #new code

    self.layerCache = QgsVectorLayerCache(layer, layer.featureCount())
    self.tableModel = QgsAttributeTableModel(self.layerCache)
    self.tableModel.loadLayer()
        
    self.tableFilterModel = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(canvas, self.tableModel)
    self.tableFilterModel.setFilterMode(QgsAttributeTableFilterModel.FilterMode.ShowAll)
        
    self.tableView.setModel(self.tableFilterModel)
    self.tableView.setSortingEnabled(True)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
    self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
```

Comment: Thanks, Seems like this would mean I would need to pass in the list of features to my custom class and then I would lose the direct relationship between the layer and the table i.e. I would have to add some code to update the table everytime the layer is update. In that case I think I'll just use the Qtablewidget object and make a custom "attribute table" using that. Unless you have a better suggestion.

Comment: See the last paragraph I have added to my answer. I hope it may help.